# Test::MockModule needs to return an array of objects with a 'getType' method

Tags: arrays, perl, unit-testing, mocking, perl-module

I'm attempting to make a unit test for perl code to mock a service which returns an array containing objects which also need to be mocked because they have a method getType() which I need to mock.

So the code which processes the results of this service call looks something like this:

```
   foreach my $set (@{$serviceResults->getValue()}) {
      next unless ($set->getType() eq 'type');
      ...
   }
```

and I'm trying to mock the service like so:

```
my $service;
my $mockService = sub {
    my (%resultValues) = @_;
    $service = mockModule(
       'My::Service',
       getValue => createMockObject(
          # how to mock the getType method?
       )
    )
};
```

And then I create a mock like this:

```
$mockService->([
    {type=>'a', data=>[0, 5]},
    {type=>'b', data=>[2, 3]}]);
```

So how do I create the mock of the getType method on each hash object in the array?  This array changes depending on the unit test, I can't use a fixed size array.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Class::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Tiny)?  It offers a very minimal, light-weight object.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

package Mockable;

use Class::Tiny qw( getType );

package main;

my $foo = Mockable->new(
    getType => 'ZZZ',
);
say $foo->getType;    # prints ZZZ
```

This will mock the method you require.  If you need something heavier, you could also look into using [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo) to create a small class and just creating objects from this class which have the accessors you need.

Comment: Interesting, but I still don't know how to handle an array of objects like this, can you show how you would solve the problem I described?